# A webpage return 404 when exist on server

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have a website on a server. When I request the homepage I get it in the browser, but when I request another webpage I don't. I have no idea why this is happening.

My website is Asp.net. The server is vps.

**Edit:**
On the local server my website working well, no problems, just in the real server it is causing problems - returns a 404 error when the page exists.

Comment: Can you give us more detail?

Comment: I edited, and added more details

Comment: Sounds like a config error to me, are you accessing the site on your local LAN or over the internet? Is it via IP address or URL?

Comment: Are you sure all the files are there on the server and you are accessing the right url? What files are these? Static html or asp or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: In the vps server the application service provider of asp.net was not active. Now when it is active all the website works well.

**Edit:**
There was also a problem in the web.config in one of the rules of rewrite tag.